# Bad results with SVM detector + HOG descriptors

Tags: opencv, svm

I have a project which i need to detect people in real time using OpenCV, my aim is use HOG descriptors to train a SVM classifier. I have trained a CvSVM with HOG features from 460 positives and 270 negatives images (samples images from GRAZ_01 dataset of INRIA: http://pascal.inrialpes.fr/data/human/). I computed HOG features for each image:

```
resize(img,img, Size(32,48));
cvtColor(img,img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
HOGDescriptor hog(Size(32,48), Size(8,8), Size(4,4), Size(4,4), 9);
hog.compute(img_gray, descriptors_values, Size(8,8), Size(0,0), locations);
```

and put it into a matrix wich i saved to xml file. My positive xml file contains a matrix with 460 rows and 2772 cols, negative xml contains a matrix with 270 rows and 2772 cols. After that I associate them with a label:

```
Mat labels(numSamples,1,CV_32FC1);
labels.rowRange(0,numPos).setTo(cv::Scalar(int(1)));
labels.rowRange(numPos,numSamples).setTo(cv::Scalar(int(-1)));
```

And I have trained a CvSVM and I converted the CvSVM into the primal form that HOGDescriptor needs for use the detector:

```
PrimalSVM model;
vector<float> detector;

train= model.train(data, labels, Mat(),Mat(),SVMParams());
model.save("SVM.xml");
model.load("SVM.xml");
model.getSupportVector(detector);

HOGDescriptor trained_hog(Size(32,48), Size(8,8), Size(4,4), Size(4,4), 9);
trained_hog.setSVMDetector(detector);
```

I get a really bad detection with this (detect so many people in a scene where just have one or two) , what am I doing wrong? please help, i'm stuck with this.

**EDIT**

I decided change the dataset for one with more samples: now I'm using a normalized positive training images centered on the person with their left-right reflections (2418 positive images) and the original negative training images (1218 negative images) of the INRIA dataset (all images are of 64x128 pixels). So, I changed the parameters for get the HOG descriptors:

```
HOGDescriptor hog(Size(64,128), Size(16,16), Size(8,8), Size(8,8), 9); 
hog.compute(img_gray, descriptors_values, Size(8,8), Size(16,16), locations);
```

And for training:

```
HOGDescriptor trained_hog(Size(64,128), Size(16,16), Size(8,8), Size(8,8), 9);
trained_hog.setSVMDetector(detector);

trained_hog.detectMultiScale(img_gray, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(16,16), 1.05, 2);
```

But now I'm getting an assertion failed:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (checkDetectorSize()) in setSVMDetector, file /Users/Fran/Documents/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.9/modules/objdetect/src/hog.cpp, line 89
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   Abort trap: 6

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you using the full-sized original images with persons anywhere inside or the cropped and centered person-only images of the INRIA dataset? In addition there might be a reason why the HOG person detectors  are trained for sth like (64,128) sizes. Probably that was the lowest well-working resolution. AND you should use much more negative samples!

Comment: thanks for your anser @Micka. I was using the original images, now I changed the dataset and now I'm using images of (64,128) size. Please take a look of edition. Thanks again!

Comment: why did you choose Size(0,0) in your initial `hog.compute(img_gray, descriptors_values, Size(8,8), Size(0,0), locations);` to arrange the training data?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/train_HOG.cpp function `compute_hog`. They just call `hog.compute( gray, descriptors, Size( 8, 8 ), Size( 0, 0 ), location );` without creating `hog` for a specific size first.